# Symfony2: Time-based Controller Action

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible, to make a time-based link / controller action in symfony2 in the annotation? With a start and a stopdate!?
For example:

```
    /**
     *@Route("/mylink", start="14.10.2015" stop="20.12.2015", name="mylink", schemes= { "http" })
    public function myLinkAction()
    {
     .....
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with having the logic _inside_ the controller? and no there is no such options.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have a link that only works at certain times?

Comment: Yes, I put the logic in the controller with a normal time difference...but I think it would be cool to handle the time, when the link is active, could be handled in the annotation

Comment: Well, you can always build your own annotations, take a look at this link, for example: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/12/symfony2-doctrine-common-creating-powerful-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend `@Route` that way but with `defaults` and I think the best solution without boilerplate code is a controller filter:

**services.yml**

```
services:
  time_range_route_filter:
    class: AppBundle\Services\TimeRangeRouteFilter
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onFilterController }
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
class DefaultController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage", defaults={"start"="2015-01-01", "end"="2016-01-01"})
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
}
```

**TimeRangeRouteFilter.php**

```
class TimeRangeRouteFilter
{
    public function onFilterController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $attributes = $request->attributes;
        $routeParams = $attributes->get('_route_params');

        $end = $routeParams['end'];
        $start = $routeParams['start'];

        if(!/* in range */) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }
    }
}
```